# How do I combine these two .htaccess rules?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to combine these two rules, but not sure how

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [L] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

when I put both, I get the error "too many redirects"

My goal here is to combine them both,

the first rule is to remove file extensions (ex. html)

the second rule is: make every URL go to https://www.example.com, rather than https://example.com

Comment: Are you trying to redirect to an external domain here, different than the requested host name? Because if not, that second rule on its own should cause the error already.

Comment: Also, not really clear what _sense_ it should make, to combine these two. The first one is an internal rewrite that adds the `.html` suffix, without showing the new URL to the user - and the second one is an external redirect. So if you combined both, the `.html` suffix _would_ be showing in the resulting URL.

Comment: In short: please invest some more time to revise your question (there is an "edit" link below, use it). Try to explain what _exactly_ you are trying to achieve instead of how you think you can achieve your goal.

Comment: @arkascha I've edited the post to elaborate more. See now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the additional information you now gave I would suggest this approach:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,END]

RewriteRule ^/?(.+)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,END]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [END]
```

In general it is a good diea to start using a `R=302` *temporary* redirection and only change that to a `R=301` *permanent* redirection once everything works as expected. That prevents nasty caching issues ...

Comment: Thank you so much! It works!

Comment: Seems to no longer be working for some reason. It was working yesterday, completely fine, now it no longer will work. I haven't edited anything other than the domain.

Comment: This is what I am met with ^^ https://i.imgur.com/UXbvOkG.png

Comment: There is little I can respond to that. You will need to start debugging - 1. check your http server's error log file for entries. 2. make sure that rewriting rule set get's applied at all, for example modify it such that it contains a definite syntax error and make a test request - what responds do you get, what appears in your error log file? 3. if you cannot gain any more information then you will have to consider rewrite logging - the documentation of the apache rewriting module explains how to enable such additional logging. It allows you to understand in details what is happening.